# How to install Delphi Chromium dcef3 in XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, chromium-embedded

I am getting problem in Installing Delphi Chromium Pack dcef3 in XE4. I want to embed webbrowser with javascript support in my application. The problem is whenever I try to compile, it displays "[dcc32 Fatal Error] F1026 File not found: 'DCEF_XE3.dpk'"

But the file exists in directory. I also loaded all dll files in the same folder. I am installing Chromium pack XE3 since package for XE4 is not available. I tried the XE5, XE2 but same error continues.

( BTW I am a student. Please guide if something are done wrong )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18852221

Comment: Thanks Ken. Now TChromium installed successfully. I added library path to chromium folder. Another problrm occured: I dropped Tchromium, and a button on the form. Whenever I build the project, windows thows an exception, "Exception EExternal Exception in libcef.dll" and application exits.
Btw I have pasted all the dll from binary folders.